# Find a matrix such that the Gram matrix is $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0& 0 \\ 0 & 1& 0 \\ 0& 0 & -1 \\ \end{smallmatrix}\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let g be a symmetric bilinear form given by the Gram matrix $
    \begin{pmatrix}
    3 & -2 & 0 \\
    -2& 2& -2 \\
    0 & -2 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$.

1. Find a basis A such that the Gram matrix in this basis is diagonal.
2. Find a basis B such that the Gram matrix is
   $     \begin{pmatrix}     1 & 0& 0 \\     0 & 1& 0 \\     0& 0 & -1 \\     \end{pmatrix} $.

I have solved the part $(1)$ but with the part $(2)$, do i need to normalize the orthogonal vectors obtained from part $1$? But how it would be related to the matrix in part $(2)$. I am confused.

Comment: What is an inner product space? What rules does it need to follow? How is a gramian matrix related to an inner product space?

Comment: It is associated with bilinear form.

Comment: What can we say about $<a,a>$ for any $a$? Any restrictions?

Comment: No there is no restriction. From the first part i can get the orthogonal basis easily. I need clarification for the second part.

Comment: $<a,a> = \|a\|^2$ can be interpreted as square of a distance in some sense. What property must we demand to hold true for distances?

Comment: Sory, i didnt get you. Why you are looking for the conditions. Because for me it seems that i need to find Basis B such that $ABA^{T}=G$ where G is matrix in part b and A is set of orthogonal basis matrx from part (a). Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86265/discussion-between-lena-and-mathreadler).